# Select element using variable not id in JQuery

Tags: jquery

How to write below statement

```
if ($('#SelectedItems option[value=' + optionData.Value + ']').length === 0) ;
```

using the variable

```
var selectedItems = $('#SelectedItems');

//Something like this but not exactly

if ($(**selectedItems** + "option[value=' + optionData.Value + ']").length === 0) ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this

```
if ($("option[value='" + optionData.Value + "']", selectedItems).length === 0)
```

This will select all the descendants of the elements in `selectedItems` which match the selector `"option[value='" + optionData.Value + "']"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('option[value="' + optionData.Value + '"]',$('#SelectedItems')).length === 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (selectedItems.find("option[value='" + optionData.value + "']").length === 0)`
should do what you're looking for.

Comment: ha, saw Dr. Molle's answer after I had already posted - I think that's a slightly better way :-)